# CSS to display contents of one element in chrome using F12 developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So just not to get distracted by all the junk around the main content, in chrome F12 edeveloper tools I add these 2 styles:

```
.content {
  display: block !important;
}

body  {
  display: none;
}
```

But then everything disappears! the similar thing works with visibility: (but the content gets strained in between invisible elements)

```
 .content * {
  visibility: visible;
}
body * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Please note `content`is changes from site to site depending on what the author of site has decided to call it's main content class, if you can use F12 developer tools with any site using the display none and all similar to above code please let me know what the syntax should be.

Also, is there a way to execute some javascript in Chrome F12 Debug Console to achieve similar result?

Comment: If the content is inside the body, then when you hide the body (with `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;`) of course everything inside will disappear.

Comment: @dingo_d : using "important!" , should overwrite that. Also note, the same thing works using visibility (without using important!) but not when using display instead.

Comment: No it shouldn't because you've made the entire body nonexistent. When you set the `display:none;` on the body, you're basically making the body block null, not displaying, nonexistent. Visibility is different, because the block exists but is just not visible.

Comment: @dingo_d that's funy, cause that is what works and I just copy and pasted it from Crome! Try for yourself and let me know if it does or doesn't work for you, maybe there is something else at work.

Comment: If you use display none on body, the entire body and it's contents will disappear, this is how display works. Use visibility as Type-Style suggested.

Comment: @Type-Style yes that does work, but it squeezes the content in between invisible elements.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot / small demo for that?
It works fine here on stackoverflow doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Using `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;` should work just fine.

Maybe you should **apply it to body and .content directly** and not all their children.

```
body {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.content {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

You can test this right here on Stack Overflow. But content is an targeted by and ID here (#content)

Comment: How is this different than what was asked in the question, yes this method works, as it was originally stated in the question. The problem is that it does not adjust the element to take the rest available area, it only hides the other elements as was original stated in the question.

Comment: I am not sure if I get it.  You want the .content to expand to the now "pseudo-empty" space?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `content` is a child of `body` so even though you are setting content to be `display: block` or `visibility: visible`. the parent element (BODY) is hidden. Therefore all of its children will be hidden too.

Comment: Thats true if you hide the body with `display: none;`.

Comment: That is not what happens, what chrome does is exactly that! Tested it and visibility works, but it does NOT remove the other elements although they are hidden. Please read my question again, because it exactly said that this does indeed work.